# LinearLayout with TextView on the left and RadioButton on the right?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, alignment, android-linearlayout

Good afternoon,

I am trying to do an alignment like this one :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h183p.png

To do it I tried the following code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0sp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dark background"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_darkbackground"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I put the layout_gravity and gravity on "right" but it does not work and look like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLbBj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dark background"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_darkbackground"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                     android:layout_gravity="right"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0sp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dark background"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_darkbackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works both ways. What is the best solution ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Relative layout is the best for this design because FrameLayout uses in different purpose.  FrameLayout purpose to work with Z-axis. That is you can stack your view elements one above the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dark background"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></View>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_darkbackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: You can use the  `<View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></View> `to fill an empty space in the middle, so that we can achieve the effect you want